Canceling out terms in rational inequalities such as $\frac{(x-3)(x+2)(x-12)}{(x+3)(x+2)(x-6)}\leq 0$
I am currently working through some rational inequalities and encountered a case where I could cancel out a common factor from the denominator and numerator of the rational inequality.
For example,
$$\frac{(x-3)(x+2)(x-12)}{(x+3)(x+2)(x-6)}\leq 0$$
I am unsure whether I should proceed with this cancellation and consider it a critical point or if holes are also considered critical points.
Thank you for your assistance.

Add an example please

((x-3)(x+2)(x-12))/((x+3)(x+2)(x-6))≤0

Thanks for helping out.

There are many great solutions which one should I pick?

When $ x \in  \mathbb{R}$, we have the following equivalence
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \frac{\left(x-3\right) \left(x+2\right) \left(x-12\right)}{\left(x+3\right) \left(x+2\right) \left(x-6\right)}  \leqslant  0 \Longleftrightarrow  \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}x+2&\neq &0\\
\displaystyle  \frac{\left(x-3\right) \left(x-12\right)}{\left(x+3\right) \left(x-6\right)}& \leqslant &0
\end{array}\right.\end{equation}
hence you can cancel the $ x+2$ provided you remember that $x =-2$ cannot be a solution.

Is this always true? What if the hole was in the x axis

I don't undertand the question. Can you give an example? What do you call a hole?

In general, you should not cancel out factors when dealing with inequalities because you are likely to confuse the solution space when using the method of intervals.
Let's look at your example:
$$\frac{(x-3)(x+2)(x-12)}{(x+3)(x+2)(x-6)} \le 0$$
Plot the roots on the number line.

Let's plot the signs, going right to left. We begin with "+" on the right of $12$, since all factors contain $x$ and not $-x$. We then switch to "-" on its left. We switch the sign again when we reach $6$ - the sign left of $6$ is now "+". When we reach $3$, the sign again switches to "-". However, when we reach $-2$, the sign does not switch because the factor $(x+2)$ appears an even number of times in the inequality. The sign then switches once we reach $-3$.

We now determine the form of each interval. We see that $(x-12)$ is only in the numerator and so $12$ will be included in the solution space. The same goes for $3$ due to $(x-3)$. However, the factors $(x+3)$ and $(x-6)$ come up only in the denominator and so the roots $-3$ and $6$ will not be part of the solution space. Now, the factor $(x+2)$ is also seen in the denominator and, therefore, $-2$ will not be part of the solution set. The solutions are
$$x \in (-3; -2) \cup (2; 3] \cup (6; 12]$$
If you were to cross out the factors of $(x+2)$, you would obtain
$$\frac{(x-3)(x-12)}{(x+3)(x-6)} \le 0$$
In this case, the method of intervals would give you

and, unless you specifically remember that $-2$ is not a solution because the inequality is not defined on it, then you would write $x \in (-3; 3] \cup (6;12]$ as the solution set, which is wrong. If the inequality has even more factors, then cancelling them out and manually keeping track of which were in the denominator gets even more error-prone.
Besides, why would you waste time writing out the cancelled-out form if you can deduce the solution set from the uncancelled one (and are more likely to do so correctly)?
